# How to use echo to wrap a variable with quotes

Tags: bash

I have a variable e.g., `pos=11111`.

I want

`echo "$pos"`, which displays

`"11111"`, instead of `11111`.

I tried to use

```
echo "\"$pos\""
```

but it missed the last quote as shown:

```
"11111
```

Is their any solution for this?

Comment: You want `"11111"`?  `echo "\"$pos\""` is the correct way to do it.  Are you sure the `pos` variable doesn't have trailing garbage that's making the second quote disappear or appear on the next line?

Comment: `pos` most likely has `11111\r` as its value; the closing quote is overwriting the initial quote because the `\r` causes the cursor to be repositioned at the start of the line. What does something like `echo "==$pos--"` output?

Answer (score 5):

I'd just use `printf` then:

```
printf '"%s"' "$pos"
```

and if you want the newline:

```
printf '"%s"\n' "$pos"
```

[printf is better than echo anyway](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

In fact the [POSIX documentation for echo](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) even says:

> New applications are encouraged to use printf instead of echo.